# does "brief personal acquaintance" here refers to an incident berfore their arrival to london or not?

Tags: meaning

does "a brief personal acquaintance" here refers to an incident berfor their arrival to london or not?

Dr. Nichols, their biographer, gives this first impression of them:
The young men, with whom I have had but **a brief personal acquaintance**,
and whom I never saw until their arrival in London, appear to me to be in
intellect and character above the average of their young countrymen,
they are not remarkable for cleverness, though of fair abilities, and Ira
has some artistic talent

Comment: Since he "never saw" them "until their arrival in London", the brief personal acquaintance must have occurred after they came to London.

Comment: Please include the source for your quotes  Ideally you can make a link to somewhere where the full text can be read online.  This looks like more of the turgid prose of ACD writing about spiritualists....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the quote clearly states "whom I never saw until their arrival in London,..."
"Dr. Nichols" seems to be qualifying his good opinion of the men by saying that he hasn't had much personal contact with them, but it's clear that all such contact happened after their arrival in London.